# PTIJ: How does Mi Yodeya have the ability to spare from death?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

In Shmuel 2:12:22, David HaMelech says:

> כִּ֤י אָמַ֙רְתִּי֙ מִ֣י יוֹדֵ֔עַ יחנני [וְחַנַּ֥נִי] יְהוָ֖ה וְחַ֥י הַיָּֽלֶד׃
>
> For I said, [with] Mi Yodeya has Hashem graced me, and the child will live.

What is it about Mi Yodeya that it could have saved the child's life? And why, as the Pesukim there relate, did it fail in this particular instance?

Furthermore, this power seems to contradict that which Shlomo HaMelech says in Mishlei 24:21-22:

> יְרָֽא־אֶת־יְהוָ֣ה בְּנִ֣י וָמֶ֑לֶךְ עִם־שׁ֝וֹנִ֗ים אַל־תִּתְעָרָֽב כִּֽי־פִ֭תְאֹם יָק֣וּם אֵידָ֑ם וּפִ֥יד שְׁ֝נֵיהֶ֗ם מִ֣י יוֹדֵֽעַ׃
>
> Fear Hashem, my son, and the king. Do not mix with dissenters, for suddenly does disaster arise, the doom that both of them [decree through] Mi Yodeya.

Is Mi Yodeya meant to be a force of good, to spare from death, or a force of destruction, the mechanism by which dissenters are destroyed?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org.il/Hosea.14.10?with=all&lang=he

Answer (score 4):

Mi Yodeya has incredible powers to change its decree of death, as it says in [Yona 3:9](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14261&st=&pgnum=192&hilite=):

מי יודע ישוב ונחם

Mi Yodeya will return and change its mind.

The king of Nineveh was wise enough to know about Mi Yodeya. That's why even though Yonah said that the people would be killed, he told everyone about Mi Yodeya.

I'll bet that until now, no one reading this knew how old Mi Yodeya really is!

Comment: Dangit, you stole my follow-up passuk. :/ This still doesn’t address MY’s usage as a harbinger of punishment.

Comment: @DonielF I guess you have to be quicker these days! Read the edit in my first sentence. I use the word "its". I think it answers OP's question.

Answer (score 4):

The answer lies in a basic policy that Mi Yodeya has, as eloquently described [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4856/4794), which gives paramount value to citing sources for the information provided. Some users adhere to this policy more strictly than others.

For those who adhere to the policy,

> כל האומר דבר בשם אומרו מביא גאולה לעולם (Megillah 16a)

and Mi Yodeya becomes a source of salvation and redemption, complete with resurrection of the dead and all that good stuff.

However, some users vaguely reference their sources with some handwaving, or omit their sources altogether, in which case

> כל שאינו אומר דבר בשם אומרו, עליו הכתוב אומר אל תגזול דל כי דל הוא (Tanchuma, Bamidbar 4)

they are stealing, which as we know from Parshas Noach, brings destruction to the world.

So you see, Mi Yodeya can really be a source of both, as [Joel referenced](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/100369/ptij-how-does-mi-yodeya-have-the-ability-to-spare-from-death#comment335322_100369).

The problem was, Dovid HaMelech thought that quoting himself counted as quoting, as he said

> כי אמרתי
>
> I said...

but, that doesn't count. He needed to cite himself in full APA format for quoting himself to count as quoting. Therefore, it didn't work, no geula, no resurrection.

Comment: Hence, “do not mix with dissenters,” i.e. the ones who dissent from site policy. I like it!

Answer (score 1):

As it says in Koheles: מִֽי־יוֹדֵ֩עַ מַה־טּ֨וֹב לָֽאָדָ֝ם בַּֽחַיִּ֗ים- Mi Yodeya (is) what is good for a man in life. We see from here that Mi Yodeya is only good in life, whereas in death, mi yodeaya is not a force of good, which would explain why the child died. Dovid thought that Mi Yodeya was a force of good in both life and death, and therefore he trusted that mi yodeya’s strength would keep the child alive. Shlomo misunderstood the story, and thought that Mi Yodeya is never a force of good. Shlomo corrected himself when he wrote Koheles